# Java многопоточность (разница между idea и онлайн компилятором)

Tags: java, многопоточность

Вопрос такой. Вот этот код (ниже), всегда выдает 0 в idea. Ввожу этот код в онлайн компилятор, выдает то что надо, так как должен работать.

```
public class Test3 {

    private int counter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test3 test3 = new Test3();
        test3.doWork();
    }

    public void doWork(){
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        });

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня ваш код выдал counter и > 0 и == 0. этож одновременное обращение к полю из 2 потоков

Comment: У меня код выдает в idea всегда 0. В онлайн компиляторе выдает рандомные числа, то есть то что и должен.

Comment: Не факт все очень сильно зависит от того как потоки будут взаимодействовать с полем

Comment: + вы не дожидаетесь этих 2 потоков

Comment: Попробуйте добавить Перез System.out.println
Thread.sleep(3000);

Comment: Ну то есть условно, вы сказали  thread1 - СТАРТУЕМ; thread2 - СТАРТУЕМ

Java программа не остановится на этом и просто выполнит System.out.println(counter)

Comment: И либо потоки не успели записать, либо случился Concurrent race condition

Comment: Да, почему то на моем пк они не успевают и выдают 0. В примере от куда я этот код взял, эти потоки успевают выдать какое либо число.

Comment: У тебя в принципе неправильно написано. Переменная модифицируется из двух потоков, но синхронизации нет никакой. При этом ещё и счётчик в основном потоке печатается без ожидания когда потоки завершатся.

Comment: "Да, почему то на моем пк они не успевают и выдают 0." - онлайн компилятор тебе мало ресурсов выделяет, а локально небось компьютер быстрый и многопроцессорный.

Comment: простым запуском 0 выдёт, и дебагером выдало 0, а если в дебагере ити step Intro F7 , то постоянно  выдаёт >10_000

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, сейчас даже чайник многопроцессорный))